# Scientific notation as numeric (not as string) in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scientific-notation

Is it possible to format a numeric value as scientific notation and still retain its format as float, for instance (and not as `str`)

If I do :

```
n = 5482.52291
type(n)
Out[115]: float
```

Then if I format `n`:

```
print(format(n, "10.2E"))
5.48E+03
```

Which is what I want, though it is a string type:

```
type(format(n, "10.2E"))
Out[118]: str
```

I also had a go with [np.format_float_scientific](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_scientific.html) but the doc string itself says already that it returns a string and doing
`float(np.format_float_scientific(n, precision=2))` will return `5480.0`

Eventually what I am trying to do is to create a MySQL database from pandas dataframes. Some columns have observations with large number (billions), such that it is best to visualise them with scientific notation. None the less, it might be at some point necessary to export the table from the SQL database and  perform (basic) mathematical operations with those observations in those columns, which won't work for `str` type.

Comment: Save both. Internally, numbers should be just that, numbers. Scientific "notation" is just a representation, as the name implies. If you want to use one and display the other, you may want to just save both and use accordingly.

Comment: I agree with Paritosh. You shouldn't mix what is best for visualization with what is best for calculations. If you want to visualize your numbers in a way that is confortable you can always create a column, a view or a container

Comment: right, thanks for the comments